# Python path in VSCode: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

After installing `VSCode` (I already have `python 2.7` on my machine), I tried to run a simple script on Windows 10 and got this error:

> [Running] /usr/bin/env python
>   "c:\Users\jim\Dropbox\projects\python\myproject\main.py" The system
>   cannot find the path specified.

So I tried to edit these settings:

[image]

And also these:

[image]

but I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Are you sure the machine cannot find the Python installation, or that it can't find the actual script itself? Can you run it from the command prompt and not inside VSCode?

Comment: the script run fine with Atom for example

Comment: Why i have this /usr/bin/env python before my script path ?

Comment: This run from command line

Answer (score 23):

It looks like you're using the Code Runner extension to run your code, and it's doing `/usr/bin/env python` instead of just `python`. Go into your User Settings and add the following:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "python": "python",
}
```

Also double-check that your python script doesn't start with the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python`, as that could also be causing the behaviour you're experiencing.

**EDIT:** Turns out there's a [`code-runner.respectShebang`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) setting for the Code Runner extension that defaults to `true`, but can be set to false to allow you to keep the shebang in the script but not use it when running the code via Code Runner:

```
{
    "code-runner.respectShebang": false
}
```

Comment: You just got me out of H3LL! Thanks!

Comment: It worked for me! What if one wants to keep the shebang line in case anyone wants to run the code from Linux? There must be a way for it to ignore the shebang line on windows.

Comment: @TimSkovJacobsen Good question. See my edit. I looked at the Code Runner settings again and turns out there's a `respectShebang` setting that's on by default, but can be set to `false` to ignore the shebang as you suggest.

Comment: I had been hung up on this for a while.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just modified `"code-runner.respectShebang": false`, and it's worked for me.