# VS Code Code runner extension: Struggling to add Python PATH to settings.json due to whitespace

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I am trying to get Code Runner to work on VS code on my Windows computer (although I use WSL most of my work involving Python). I have installed Python using Anaconda

`C:\\Users\\FirstName LastName\\anaconda3\\python.exe`

You might notice the whitespace in the file path.

And I have added it to my `settings.json`...

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "python.dataScience.sendSelectionToInteractiveWindow": true,
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "C:\\Users\\FirstName LastName\\anaconda3\\python.exe",
    },
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [

    
    ]
}
```

... and yet I keep getting this error when I run a Python script using Code Runner:

```
[Running] C:\Users\FirstName LastName\anaconda3\python.exe "c:\Users\FirstName LastName\Documents\PythonFolder\pythonscript.py"
'C:\Users\FirstName' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Looks like it's not happy with the whitespace there. I checked out a solution proposed in another question, whichw as to add `"python": "python"` to `settings.json`, but that just gave me this:

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: I think you have to escape the whitespace like this `C:\\Users\\FirstName\ Name\\anaconda3\\python.exe`. lmk if that works, or do as i did and install anaconda in a custom location (e.g. `C:\\anaconda\`) to avoid whitespace issues, btw, the anaconda installer also recommends installing python in a path without spaces because some python libraries don't handle that properly on windows.

Comment: Have you added `python` to your system PATH? Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52458064/9374673) solve your problem?

Comment: @HaleemurAli I just tried it and it didn't work, it just removed the whitespace, `C:\\Users\\FirstNameLastName\\anaconda3\\python.exe`

Comment: @MihaiChelaru Unfortunately when I add `"code-runner.executorMap": {"python": "python",},"code-runner.respectShebang": false,` I just get the same error: `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: You need to [add Python to your system PATH](https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path). I suspect you'd get the same error if you went into `cmd.exe` and ran `python`. Doing this will help you in general, since you will likely come across this error again in the future if you ever want to run `python` from a terminal.

Comment: did installing to `c:\\anaconda3` help?

Comment: So it turns out I wasn't running VS Code in WSL, which is what I wanted. Adding  `"code-runner.executorMap": {"python": "python",},"code-runner.respectShebang": false` was enough to get it running, thank you! @HaleemurAli I think I might try to reinstall anaconda any to avoid the whitespace problem in the future

Answer (score 1):

Edit your code-runner setting.json and add this setting:

1.From [this Qiita post](https://qiita.com/take_me/items/6a1d2d417889837219d1)

```
{
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "python -u",
    },
}
```

Or
2.From [this StackOverFlow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541747/how-do-you-get-the-code-runner-extension-in-visual-studio-code-to-use-the-select)

```
{
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python":"$pythonPath $fullFileName",
    },
}
```

Or 3.From [this NewBeDev post](https://newbedev.com/how-to-setup-code-runner-in-visual-studio-code-for-python)

```
 {
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "$pythonPath -u $fullFileName",
    },
}
```

Just try one of them!